# How do I copy text to the clipboard in JS?

Tags: javascript, email

I would like to put a copy paste on the email, when clicking on the email, the email is copied automatically. I've tried several techniques but I can't.

Here is my code:

```
    content += '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th>Nom</th><th>Prénom</th><th>Companie</th><th>Tags</th><th class="copy">Email</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    JSON.parse(data).forEach(id => {
     
      content += '<tr>';
      content += '<td>' + id.lastname + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + id.firstname + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + id.company + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + id.tags + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + id.email + '</td>';
      content += '</tr>';
    });
```

Comment: Copied from where to where? Is it actually relevant that it's an e-mail, or is it just a block of text? What happens when you run the code shown - do you get any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: _"I've tried several techniques but I can't."_ - that is pretty useless information. We are not here to provide tutorials for you, based on nothing more than you telling us that you were not able to get it done yourself. _Show us_ some of the stuff you tried, and give a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: copy and past like (ctrl+c)

Answer (score 0):

the main issue come from this line `let mail = tabStudents.email;` tabstudents is not define and in the process you try to do it's from the iterator of the foreach loop

in my sample i renamed it student

```
JSON.parse(data).forEach(student => {
let mail = student.email;
```

here the full sample

```js
function displayPopup(data) {
  if (data) { // si data n'est pas vide
    let content = '';

    let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    let contentModal = document.getElementById("modal-body");
    let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    content += '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th>Nom</th><th>Prénom</th><th>Companie</th><th>Tags</th><th class="copy">Email</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    JSON.parse(data).forEach(student => {
      let mail = student.email;
      console.log(mail)
      content += '<tr>';
      content += '<td>' + student.lastname + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + student.firstname + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + student.company + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + student.tags + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + student.email + '</td>';
      content += '</tr>';
    });

    content += '</tbody></table>';

    contentModal.innerHTML = content;
    modal.style.display = "block"

    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

displayPopup('[{"id": 1, "email":"test@test.r"}]');
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="modal-body">
    <span class="close"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```